# WARMR (ACE suite): eliminate "connected" terms from frequent patterns

Tags: machine-learning, prolog, data-mining, swi-prolog, logic-programming

i am using the WARMR frequent pattern algorithm in the ACE data mining suite. here is a toy example illustrating my problem.

imagine you have, say, 20 examples (`example(ex1))`,...,`example(ex20))`) and only one predicate, call it `quality`, so `quality(E, X)` means `E` has quality `X`. `X` can take, say, 6 values: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` which are related: `c` is `b` and `b` is `a` (and so `c` is also `a`), `f` is `e` and `e` is `d` (and so `f` is also `d`). think graphs:

```
a - b - c
d - e - f
```

when WARMR mines for frequent patterns, once one quality in a branch/graph is included no other quality from the same branch should be allowed to be added. for example at level 3:

```
 example(A),quality(A,a),quality(A,d)
```

is a valid pattern but:

```
 example(A),quality(A,a),quality(A,c)
```

or

```
 example(A),quality(A,a),quality(A,b)
```

are not.

i have included this background knowledge in the `.bk` file:

```
bond(b,a).
bond(c,b).
bond(f,e).
bond(e,d).

no_bond(a,d).
no_bond(a,e).
no_bond(a,f).

bond(X,Y) :- bond(X,Z),bond(Z,Y).
bond(X,Y) :- bond(Y,X).

no_bond(X,Y) :- no_bond(Y,X).
no_bond(X,Y) :- no_bond(X,Z),bond(Z,Y).
```

and i have tried to impose the above condition via the following in the `.s` file:

```
rmode(quality(+E, #).
constraint(quality(E, Q), not_occurs(bond(Q,_))).
```

and

```
rmode(quality(+E, #).
constraint(quality(E, Q), user(X, no_bond(Q,_))).
```

or

```
constraint(quality(E, Q), user(X, no_bond(Q,X))).
```

none of which worked. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks very cool, it's kind of a shame that ACE is not open source.

Comment: @DanielLyons you should e-mail the maintainer to ask if you can get access if you are interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the following answer has been suggested to me:

first add the following predicates to the background knowledge:

```
branch1(E,X) :- quality(E,X), member(X, [a,b,c]).
branch2(E,X) :- quality(E,X), member(X, [d,e,f]).
```

then include these in the settings file:

```
rmode(1:branch1(+E,#)).
rmode(1:branch2(+E,#)).
```

this solves my stated problem. however, data in my actual problem forms a directed tree, so this 'static' branches approach does not apply.